# Troubleshooting unexpected T_PUBLIC error

Tags: php

I get this error...

> Parse error:syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in C:\filename here on line 12

On this line....

```
public static function getInstance(){
```

The code...

```
<?PHP
class Session{

 private static $instance;

 function __construct() {
 {
  session_start();
  echo 'Session object created<BR><BR>';
 }

 public static function getInstance(){
  if (!self::$instance) {
   self::$instance = new Session();
  }
  return self::$instance;
 }
}
```

Comment: When you have a syntax error, double check all control characters like {, }, ; etc.

Comment: I had this error and it was because I tried declaring a public function _outside_ of a class. When I saw the code snippets in this question, it helped me realize this. The question was closed, but the ultimate answer to this question is that a member cannot be declared `public` unless it is directly in a class. In the case of this question, the extra curly brace led the interpreter to interpret 'getInstance' as being declared within the `__construct` function, which is not a class. I would like to add this as an answer to others in the future who encounter this syntax error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<?PHP
class Session{

    private static $instance;

    function __construct() 
    {
        session_start();
        echo 'Session object created<BR><BR>';
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new Session();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Try that. You had an extra bracket.

The error was actually in the line `function __construct()`. It created a function and then an empty set of brackets (doesn't actually error).

Then, you never ended up breaking out of the construct function so it error-ed when you tried to use the public parameter inside a function, which is not valid syntax.

This is why we make consistent bracket placement, so we always put stuff in the same place, and thus can easily spot mis-placements.

Comment: Thanks I am really going crazy for like an hour with this now, it's always something obvious it seems

Answer (score 2):

In other words, you have a syntax error:

```
function __construct() { <-- note the extra open curly
{ <-- note the extra open curly
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem and then i found out that the curly braces "{" of my class was missing .